# Error al detectar directorio de red desde servicio de windows c#

Tags: c#, windows-service

Tengo un servicio de windows que lee un directorio de ficheros, los procesa y guarda ciertos datos en una BD, cuando el fichero debe leer una ruta del PC donde esta instalado lo hace correctamente, pero no he logrado que lea un directorio de red.

Tengo dos unidades de red lan creadas en el equipo que apuntan a directorios:

```
\\192.168.68.21\data
\\192.168.68.22\data
```

Pero cuando intento verificar que el directorio existe de esta forma:

```
string pathBD = Path.Combine(@"\\192.168.68.21\Data", i.ToString(), month);
if (Directory.Exists(pathBD)){
 ...
}
else{
  FileLog.Write("El fichero no existe");
}
```

Siempre me reporta el log que el directorio no existe, por mas que si pueda acceder a la ruta a través del explorador de windows, cabe anotar que este mismo código si puede acceder a ese directorio si se ejecuta desde una aplicación de consola, por lo que me indica que para hacerlo desde el windows service necesita una instrucción extra que desconozco.

Comment: Podria ser un tema de permisos. Intenta ejecutarlo como administrador

Comment: Para asignarle privilegios de administrador al servicio se requiere algún tipo de instrucción en el código?

Comment: Abre la lista de servicios de windows, busca  tu servicio en la lista, dale doble click, ve al segundo tab donde dice algo de log on o session, y alli pon usuario que tenga acceso a la ruta de red.

Comment: https://forsenergy.com/es-es/sys_srv/html/f31817d0-be22-463f-84a9-eeb271b37014.htm

Comment: La solución planteada por Cristina Carrasco me ha funcionado, si pudiese plantearla como respuesta la marcaría como solución.